# Describe the completion of $\mathcal B(X,Y)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$,$Y$ be normed spaces, and $\mathcal B(X,Y)$ be the space ob bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. Then $\mathcal B(X,Y)$ is a normed space. Denote be $\overline{\mathcal B(X,Y)}$ its completion.

What elements are in this completion, are they still operators from $X$ to $Y$?

I think $\overline{\mathcal B(X,Y)}$ should be isomorphic to $\mathcal B(X,\overline Y)$, is it true?

Comment: I assume you mean that $\overline{\mathcal{B}(X, Y)}$ should be isomorphic to $\mathcal{B}(X, \overline{Y})$?

Comment: @AJY right, that what I mean!

Comment: If you weren't already aware, you're correct that $\mathcal{B} \left( X, \overline{Y} \right)$ is complete, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164158/proving-that-the-space-of-bounded-linear-operators-is-complete. Your claim sounds reasonable, but after a bit of tinkering, I'm not sure how to show that $\mathcal{B} \left( X, \overline{Y} \right)$ is *the* completion of $\mathcal{B}(X, Y)$.

Comment: $B(X,\overline{Y})$ is not generally the completion of $B(X,Y)$. As an example let $X=c_0(\Bbb N)$ (the space of sequences convering to $0$ with sup-norm) and $Y= c_{00}(\Bbb N)$ (the space of finite sequences) with the same norm, so that $\overline Y= X$. Then the identity map $B(c_0(\Bbb N), c_0(\Bbb N)$ cannot be approximated in norm by maps in $B(c_0(\Bbb N), c_{00}(\Bbb N))$.

Comment: @s.harp Can you  give hint for "cannot be approximated ".

Comment: @MeetPatel Let $T:c_0(\Bbb N)\to c_{00}(\Bbb N)$ approximating the identity so that $\|T(x)-x\|\leq \frac12$ for all $x$. If $e_n$ is the element of $c_0(\Bbb N)$ having a $1$ at position $n$ and else $0$, one finds that $T(e_n)$ has a non-vanishing $e_n$ component. Note however that each $T(x)\in c_{00}$, so there is some $n(x)$ after which all components vanish. Then one checks $T(\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}e_{n_k})$ is not in $c_{00}$, where $n_k=n(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} 2^{-j} e_{n_{j}})$ is defined inductively.